# How to remove certain results from my search count?

Tags: sql

I received a few irrelevant results to my count that I would like to remove from my output.

When using only the first "where lower (person) not like '%c%'" worked but when adding person b, c etc. as shown it gave me the original irrelevant results.

What should I change?

```
SELECT
    person,
    COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count_distinct_urls
FROM
    project.dataset.keyword
WHERE
    LOWER(person) NOT LIKE '%b%' 
    OR LOWER(person) NOT LIKE '%c%' 
    OR LOWER(person) NOT LIKE '%e%' 
    OR LOWER(person) NOT LIKE '%f%' 
GROUP BY
    person
ORDER BY
    count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
    5;
```

Expected results:

```
Row person  count_mentions  count_distinct_urls 
-----------------------------------------------
1     a          ---               ----
2     d 
3     g
4     h
5     i
```

Comment: Could you please provide the actual results as well? Also, why do you expect these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `AND`, not `OR`:

```
where lower(person) not like '%b%' and
      lower(person) not like '%c%' and
      lower(person) not like '%e%' and
      lower(person) not like '%f%'
```

This is logically equivalent to:

```
where not (lower(person) like '%b%' or
           lower(person) not like '%c%' or
           lower(person) not like '%e%' or
           lower(person) not like '%f%' 
          )
```

Or more concisely:

```
 where not regexp_contains(person, '[BbCcEeFf]')
```

Or if you want to be a bit inscrutable:

```
where not regexp_contains(person, '(?i)[bcef]')
```

The `(?i)` makes the pattern matching case-insensitive.